# clang AST Matcher: Whats the best way to match the current Matcher over hasParent()

Tags: c++, clang, libtooling

I am trying to search for `ifStmt`s, which aren't an `else if`. To accomplish that, I want to test if the Stmt has a Parent, which is not an `ifStmt(hasElse(ifStmt(equals(<myCurrentNode>))))`

The following obviously does not work, but I could not find a better solution.

```
clang-query> m ifStmt(<myMatcherforMyNode>, unless(hasParent(ifStmt(hasElse(ifStmt(equalsBoundNode("ifelse"))))))).bind("ifelse")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok just found it out myself by searching the source of clang-tidy:

Just use something like `ifStmt(ifStmt().bind("if"), <myMatcherForMyNode>, unless(hasParent(ifStmt(hasElse(ifStmt(equalsBoundNode("if")))))))`.

Also, `ifStmt(stmt().bind("if"), <myMatcherForMyNode>, unless(hasParent(ifStmt(hasElse(ifStmt(equalsBoundNode("if")))))))` will do the job